# XSLT Transformation connect nodes with same names with parent node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to transform the following XML-data to the desired output shown below - without success until now. So I hope of an input from an expert relating the xsl. Thank you in advance.

**Input XML-Data**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
   <page number="1">
     <pageArticles>
         <articleID id="100"/>
         <articleID id="200"/>
         <articleID id="300"/>
     </pageArticles>
   </page>
   <page number="5">
      <pageArticles/>
   </page>
   <page number="9">
      <pageArticles>
         <articleID id="400"/>
         <articleID id="500"/>                 
      </pageArticles>
   </page>
</pages>
```

**Desired Ouput**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
  <page>
     <number>1</number>
     <articleID>100</articleID>
  </page>
  <page>
     <number>1</number>
     <articleID>200</articleID>
  </page>
  <page>
     <number>1</number>
     <articleID>300</articleID>
  </page>
  <page>
     <number>5</number>
     <articleID></articleID>
  </page>
  <page>
     <number>9</number>
     <articleID>400</articleID>
  </page>
  <page>
     <number>9</number>
     <articleID>500</articleID>
  </page>
</pages>
```

Many thanks in advance for any assistance!
Urs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT-1.0 stylesheet does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/pages">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//articleID | pageArticles[not(*)]">
    <page>
        <number><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::page/@number[1]" /></number>
        <articleID><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></articleID>
    </page>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
<pages>
   <page>
      <number>1</number>
      <articleID>100</articleID>
   </page>
   <page>
      <number>1</number>
      <articleID>200</articleID>
   </page>
   <page>
      <number>1</number>
      <articleID>300</articleID>
   </page>
   <page>
      <number>5</number>
      <articleID/>
   </page>
   <page>
      <number>9</number>
      <articleID>400</articleID>
   </page>
   <page>
      <number>9</number>
      <articleID>500</articleID>
   </page>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a template for those `articleID` elements to collect the number from the grandparent and add a template for empty `pageArticles`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="pages">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="page/pageArticles"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pageArticles[not(has-children())]">
      <page>
          <number>{../@number}</number>
          <articleID/>
      </page>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="articleID">
      <page>
          <number>{../../@number}</number>
          <articleID>{@id}</articleID>
      </page>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2BT and the above is XSLT 3. In earlier version of XSLT you have to replace the text value templates (e.g. `{../@number}`) with `xsl:value-of` (e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="../@number"/>`) and the predicate `[not(has-children())]` with `[not(node()]`.

Comment: Dear Martin
Thank you very much for the really fast reply that helped to solve my problem.
Your reference to XSLT 3 was also very helpful. Kind regards Urs